# SQLAlchemy Event interface

Tags: python, events, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 0.7. I would like some 'post-processing' to occur after a `session.flush()`, namely, I need to access the instances involved in the `flush()` and iterate through them. The flush() call will update the database, but the instances involved also store some data in an LDAP database, I would like SQLAlchemy to trigger an update to that LDAP database by calling an instance method.

I figured I'd be using the `after_flush(session, flush_context)` event, detailed [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.after_flush), but how do I get a list of `update()'d` instances?

On a side note, how can I determine which columns have changed (or are 'dirty') on an instance. I've been able to find out if an instance as a whole is dirty, but not individual properties.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [link you provided](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.after_flush):

> Note that the session’s state is still in pre-flush, i.e. ‘new’, ‘dirty’, and ‘deleted’ lists still show pre-flush state as well as the history settings on instance attributes.

This means that you should be able to get an access of all the `dirty` objects in the `session.dirty` list. You'll note that the first parameter of the event callback is the current `session` object.

As for the second part, you can use the [sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.get_history](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html?highlight=flush#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.get_history) function to figure out which columns have been changed. It returns a [History](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html?highlight=flush#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.History) object for a given attribute which contains a `has_changes()` method.

If you're trying to listen for changes on specific class attributes, consider using [Attribute Events](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html#attribute-events) instead.

Comment: I agree. `session.new` and `session.dirty` will work. But Attribute Events won't have the history you're looking for. I included a detailed example in another post if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642286/how-can-i-get-a-sqlalchemy-orm-objects-previous-state-after-a-db-update/15671586#15671586