# How can I get a SQLAlchemy ORM object's previous state after a db update?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, crud

The issue is that I can't figure out how to use SQLAlchemy to notify me when an object goes into a new state.

I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM (Declarative) to update an object:

```
class Customer(declarative_base()):

    __table_name__ = "customer"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    status = Column(String)
```

I want to know when an object enters a state. Particularly after an UPDATE has been issued and when the state changes. E.g. `Customer.status == 'registered'` and it previously had a different state.

I'm currently doing this with an `'set'` attribute event:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from model import Customer

def on_set_attribute(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    print target.status
    print value
    print oldvalue

event.listen(
        Customer.status,
        'set',
        on_set_attribute,
        propagate=True,
        active_history=True)
```

My code fires every time 'set' is called on that attribute, and I check if the `value` and the `oldvalue` are different. The problem is that the `target` parameter isn't fully formed so it doesn't have all the attribute values populated yet.

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution was to use 'after_flush' SessionEvent instead of 'set' AttributeEvent.

Many thanks to [agronholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242021/agronholm) who provided example SessionEvent code that specifically checked an object's value and oldvalue.

The solution below is a modification of his code:

```
def get_old_value(attribute_state):
    history = attribute_state.history
    return history.deleted[0] if history.deleted else None


def trigger_attribute_change_events(object_):
    for mapper_property in object_mapper(object_).iterate_properties:
        if isinstance(mapper_property, ColumnProperty):
            key = mapper_property.key
            attribute_state = inspect(object_).attrs.get(key)
            history = attribute_state.history

            if history.has_changes():
                value = attribute_state.value
                # old_value is None for new objects and old value for dirty objects
                old_value = get_old_value(attribute_state)
                handler = registry.get(mapper_property)
                if handler:
                    handler(object_, value, old_value)


def on_after_flush(session, flush_context):
    changed_objects = session.new.union(session.dirty)
    for o in changed_objects:
        trigger_attribute_change_events(o)

event.listen(session, "after_flush", on_after_flush)
```

The `registry` is a dictionary whose keys are MapperProperty's and whose values are event handlers.
`session`, `event`, `inspect`, and `object_mapper` are all sqlalchemy classes and functions.

Answer (score 2):

use the [before_update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_update) event or the [before_flush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.before_flush) event to intercept this happening at a later point in time.